# Выборка sql по двум таблицам

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы.

```
CREATE TABLE photos (
    photo_id int NOT NULL,
    photo_title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (photo_id)
); 

CREATE TABLE comments (
    comment_id int NOT NULL,
    photo_id int  NOT NULL,
    user_id int  NOT NULL,
    comment_text varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (comment_id)
);
```

Как написать запрос sql, который выведет картинки и кол-во комментов к ним, упорядочив по возрастанию количества, у которых меньше 4 пользователей оставивших комменты?

Answer (score 2):

```
select p.photo_title, c.* from photos p
join (
    select  c.photo_id, count(distinct c.user_id) comments 
    from    comments c
    group by c.photo_id
    having   count(distinct c.user_id) < 4
    ) as c
on c.photo_id = p.photo_id
order by  comments
```

Если несколько комментариев от одного пользователя надо учитывать, то из запроса надо убрать distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Вот на диалекте sql Oracle.

```
select photo_title, count(*) as cnt
from photos p, comments c
where p.photo_id=c.photo_id
group by photo_title
having count(*)<4
order by 2 desc
```